# How do I convert a string+offset value to a DateTimeOffset without adding-then-subtracting the offset?

Tags: .net, .net-core

Our app interacts with an API that returns local datetime strings in the format `yyyyMMdd HH:mm` with a secondary number field indicating the UTC offset in hours.

We're successfully handling this with the following code.

```cs
DateTimeOffset ParseWeirdDateTime(string dateTimeString, double utcOffset)
{
    DateTimeOffset dateTimeOffset = DateTimeOffset.ParseExact(
        dateTimeString,
        "yyyyMMdd HH:mm",
        CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal
    );

    return dateTimeOffset.AddHours(-utcOffset).ToOffset(TimeSpan.FromHours(utcOffset));
}

string localDateTimeString = "20231108 14:30";
double utcOffset = -4;
DateTimeOffset dateTimeParsed = ParseWeirdDateTime(localDateTimeString, utcOffset);
// comes out to 11/8/2023 2:30:00 PM -04:00
```

My question is, is there a better way to handle this? Though this works, it feels clunky to parse to a UTC DateTimeOffset, only to apply the inverse of the offset and finally convert to the offset.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- You say your `yyyyMMdd HH:mm` input strings represent a "local" (or rather: non-UTC) instant, but...

  - You're using `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact` even though the input string does not represent a `Date+Time+Offset` tuple: the string only represents a `Date+Time+Undefined-Offset` tuple.

    - So use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead, and ensure it has `DateTimeKind.Unspecified` (because no offset data is specified at-this-point).
    - (btw, **never** use `DateTimeKind.Local`: it specifically refers to the *local computer's time*, which is almost always useless in business applications because it isn't invariant like real UTC is: consider local timezones, political timezone changes, daylight savings, machine misconfiguration, etc).
  - Also, you're incorrectly using `DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal`, which doesn't apply here because the string you're passing-in does not represent a UTC value. As [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.datetimestyles?view=net-7.0) states "*If no time zone is specified in the parsed string, the string is assumed to denote a UTC.*"

I'd do it like so:

- As the `dateTimeString` value only represents a date+time value *without an offset* I use `DateTime.ParseExact` instead of `DateTimeOffset.ParseExact`.
- Use `DateTimeStyles.None` as `AssumeUniversal` is incorrect here.
- Then I adjust the `DateTime` value *to* a `DateTimeOffset` via the ctor.

```cs
/// <summary><see href="https://stackoverflow.com/a/77449580/159145" /></summary>
static DateTimeOffset ParseWeirdDateTime( String dateTimeString, Double utcOffsetInHours /* Always specify units in names when using dimensionless types */ )
{
    DateTime instantInTimeWithUndefinedOffset = DateTime.ParseExact(
        s       : dateTimeString,
        format  : "yyyyMMdd HH:mm",
        provider: CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
        style   : DateTimeStyles.None
    );
    
    Debug.Assert( instantInTimeWithUndefinedOffset.Kind == DateTimeKind.Unspecified );

    return new DateTimeOffset( instantInTimeWithUndefinedOffset, offset: TimeSpan.FromHours( utcOffsetInHours ) );
}
```

Comment: I like it. It's similar to my approach, but the intent is much more clear.